# Inconsistent results when running the same neural network in TensorFlow vs Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, mnist

I created two identical neural networks for the MNIST dataset, one using TensorFlow and one using Keras. At 10 epochs, Keras achieves over 96% performance, while TensorFlow achieves about 70%.

I have tested the codes below on other datasets as well, and TensorFlow achieved much lower performance on all of them in a direct parameter comparison.

Keras Code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist

# Loading MNIST
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data() 

# Converting the y-value column to an array of classes (one hot enconding)
from keras.utils import np_utils
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train) 
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)

# Changing the shape of input images and normalizing
x_train = x_train.reshape((60000, 784))
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape((10000, 784))
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255

# Making the neural network
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=784, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(30, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(10, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax')) 

from keras.optimizers import Adam
optimizer = Adam()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['acc'])

# Training and showing the results
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=200, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=1)
```

TensorFlow Code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import tensorflow as tf

#Loading MNIST
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

# Epochs parameters
epochs = 10
batch_size = 200

# Neural network parameters
n_input = 784 
n_hidden_1 = 30 
n_hidden_2 = 30 
n_classes = 10 

# Placeholders x, y
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

# Creating the first layer 
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1]))
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x,w1),b1))

# Creating the second layer 
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2]))
layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1,w2),b2)) 

# Creating the output layer 
w_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
bias_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
output = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, w_out), bias_out)

# Loss function
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = output, labels = y))
# Optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

# Making predictions
predictions = tf.equal(tf.argmax(output, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

# Accuracy
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(predictions, tf.float32))

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Opening the session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)  
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.0
        total_batches = int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)

        # Loop through all batch iterations
        for i in range(total_batches):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

            # Fit training
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

            # Computing the average cost of a complete epoch
            avg_cost += sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y}) / total_batches

        # Running accuracy (with test data) on each epoch
        accuracy_test = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels})

        # Showing results after each epoch
        print ("Epoch: ", "{},".format((epoch + 1)), "Average cost = ", "{:.3f}".format(avg_cost))
        print ("Accuracy Test = ", "{:.3f}".format(accuracy_test))  
    print ("Training completed!")
    print ("Model Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Could anyone help me understand what may be causing this divergence?

Answer (score 0):

Normalization drastically improves a model's accuracy.

In the keras code you have performed normalization on data, however I can't find any normalization done in the tensorflow code or perhaps the mnist data in tensorflow is already normalized at source?

> Please verify that mnist data in tensorflow code is also normalized

Comment: Hi Reuben, I've already checked. The MNIST dataset in TensorFlow is already normalized. I even tested these codes with other datasets and TensorFlow is always underperforming..so I believe this is not the point

Comment: @guitarai Okay, I found that MNIST dataset in tensorflow is split into 3 parts, 55,000 data points of training data (mnist.train), 10,000 points of test data (mnist.test), and 5,000 points of validation data (mnist.validation). In keras, you're using 60,000 data points for training. Perhaps this makes a difference.

Comment: Maybe, but I think the performance gap shouldn't be that big. In another test, I used the Keras dataset as input to TensorFlow, and the result was similar.

Comment: Reuben thank you for your help. I did a new test as you suggested using the same dataset, if you can take a look, the results were the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009865/why-is-tensorflow-having-a-worse-accuracy-than-keras-in-direct-comparison